# In magento..How Can I Change My Product Category From Front-end

Tags: magento

im inserting Category for the product like this.

$designer=$_POST['desig'];
$product->setCategoryIds(array($designer));

Comment: please be little explanatory

Comment: Im PHP developer..now im working on customizing magento...I'm Adding Products From Front-end(user) Successfully.and Editing and Updating Also Done except Updating Product Category.How Can I Change My Product Category From Front-end(At editing  my product).

Answer (score 0):

In PHP code you can put them into the category while you are importing them.
Say you have a product called $product and a category ID called $category_id
You can put it into a category by doing the following code

```
$product->setCategoryIds(array($category_id));
$product->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use as follows :

```
define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

// Load products 
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)
            ->getAll();

// Load categories
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
            ->setStoreId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$categories = $category->getAll();
foreach($products as $product) {
    // Get relevant category 
    $product->setCategoryIds(array($category->getId()));
    $product->save();
}
```

you might need to do few tweaks with above code to make it compatible to your need.